# Python Error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, typeerror

Below is my code and the error I am getting

```
import requests
import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?  q=hardware+engineer&l=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class", "jobtitle"})

print job_titles
```

Error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "webscraping.py", line 13, in <module>
    job_titles = soup.find_all("a", {"class", "jobtitle"})
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is working to me- `jobtitle` is class name of `h2` not `a`. I am with `bs4 '4.4.0'`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.indeed.com/jobs?  q=hardware+engineer&l=San+Francisco%2C+CA"

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

job_titles = soup.find_all("h2", {"class", "jobtitle"})

for job in job_titles:
    print job.text.strip()
```

Prints-

```
Management Associate - Access & Channel Management
Airline Customer Service Agent (Korean Speaker preferred) SF...
Event Concierge
Flight Checker
Office Automation Clerk
Administrative Assistant III
Operations Admin I - CA
Cashier Receptionist, Grade 3, (Temporary)
Receptionist/Office Assistant
Full-Time Center Associate
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you're using [BeautifulSoup 3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) which does not have `find_all`, but only `findAll`.

Use [`findAll`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method:%20findAll(name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20**kwargs)) if you will use BeautifulSoup 3.

Or use [BeautifulSoup 4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4) to use [`find_all`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Answer (score 1):

It shows that soup.find_all is None. Make sure that it's not none. Moreover, one more suspicious thing I notices in your code is imports

```
import BeautifulSoup
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
```

Make sure that you import any one of them and accordingly modify

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```